# Getting DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG in Amazon, probably bad dns configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I did set up this Amazon lightsail instance.
I transfered a domain Amazon Route 53 from another webhost

I set up a new DNS record in the hosted zone with a simple "A" rule of redirection to the IP adress of my lightsail instance.

But everytime I navigate to mydomain.com

I get the error:

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

And the website is unreachable.

Sorry if it's a basic question, I am a lttle new to this and I need help
Thank you

The domain:
https://www.dietaesport.com/

Comment: DNS issues are near-impossible to debug if you don’t share the actual domain name. Update your question and include the domain name, after all domain names are public so there’s no need to redact them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nameservers still point to your previous hosting:

```
$ dig ns dietaesport.com. @e.gtld-servers.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dietaesport.com.    172800  IN  NS  dns2.technorail.com.
dietaesport.com.    172800  IN  NS  dns.technorail.com.
dietaesport.com.    172800  IN  NS  dns4.arubadns.cz.
dietaesport.com.    172800  IN  NS  dns3.arubadns.net.
```

Those servers (no longer?) know about the domain.

If you've got a *Hosted Zone* in Route53 you'll have to update the registrar to use the the Route53 nameservers.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: yeah probably that is the problem.
Even if in the hosted zone control panels NS records seem the correct ones

Comment: Take the nameservers from the Route53 *hosted zone* NS record and put them to the domain nameservers section in the Route53 *domain registration*. They are two different things that must be aligned.